# Window.scroll not working in augular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, window, scrolltop

I tried to alert a message if the user has scrolled to the bottom. I am using angularJS and it did not seem to be working.

```
app.controller('MainController',function($scope, $rootScope, $route, $http, $timeout){

  // overflow auto 
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           alert("bottom!");
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Any helps?

Comment: FYI  it's not recommended to bind events in the controller.
You should make a directive for that.
Anyway do you have console errors?

Comment: Also, you can inject `$window` object into your controller or your directive. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting there. As Dvir pointed out, it will be easier to test your controller if you keep all DOM interaction in directives. So, you can do it like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                $(window).scroll(function() {   
                   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                       alert("bottom!");
                   }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdvjjav2/1/

Comment: I think this is a nice way if you don't wish to use the 'ng-infinite-scroll' module and accomplish the simple infinite scroll.